# Intel igb driver - PCIe link lost

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 (5.4.0-70-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP) with Intel Gigabit 82580 4-ports

After boot:

```
[    3.400584] igb 0000:02:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[    3.400913] igb 0000:02:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:5.0Gb/s:Width x4) 00:1b:21:a7:56:5c
[    3.401240] igb 0000:02:00.0: eth0: PBA No: Unknown
[    3.401597] igb 0000:02:00.0: Using MSI-X interrupts. 8 rx queue(s), 8 tx queue(s)
[    3.593189] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: renamed from eth0
[   10.289868] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: igb: enp2s0f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

After a while:

```
[ 1088.883151] igb 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: PCIe link lost
```

Check `lspci`

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev ff)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev ff)
02:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev ff)
02:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Network Connection (rev ff)
```

Check `/sys`

```
$ sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*02:00
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb/0000:02:00.2
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb/0000:02:00.0
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb/0000:02:00.3
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb/0000:02:00.1
```

I tried also to reload the igb driver:

```
$ modprobe -r igb
$ modprobe igb
```

But I got:

```
[63576.736878] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.6.0-k
[63576.736879] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[63576.756936] igb 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[63576.757258] igb 0000:02:00.0 0000:02:00.0 (uninitialized): PCIe link lost
[63577.080906] igb 0000:02:00.0: PHY reset is blocked due to SOL/IDER session.
[63578.798966] igb 0000:02:00.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[63578.813006] igb: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

I also tried to use `pcie_aspm=off` based on answer below but it didn't work either.

https://serverfault.com/questions/193114/linux-e1000e-intel-networking-driver-problems-galore-where-do-i-start

Any suggestion to fix it? Could be a hardware problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solutions**, as suggested in references.
YMMV.

1. Try ([ref](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1442638)):

   ```
   $ modprobe -r igb
   $ sleep 1
   $ modprobe igb
   $ sleep 1
   $ systemctl restart network
   ```
2. The problem may be related to the driver, depending on the kernel version. So you may try updating the kernel (currently 5.8.0 is available, and even 5.11.0 if manually installing it). If you, for any reason, cannot use those newer kernels, at least it will help you with the diagnosis.
3. Apparently, using older kernels may also get rid of the problem.
   I found no specific information on which transition introduced the problem, but it is not hard to try also with earlier kernels, at least for diagnosing the problem.

**Suggestions** to increase your chances of getting help and the problem solved:

1. Post some context lines about `... PCIe link lost`.
2. Whenever you post the output of a command, post the exact command that you used to produce it.
3. Specify where you used `pcie_aspm=off`.
4. Post the output or result of each specific solution suggested (or, if you did not try it, at least mention why, so others know).
5. Update the question with the added information, instead of posting it scattered in comments. And reorganize slightly if that improves readability.

**Related**

1. https://community.ipfire.org/t/intermittent-problem-with-intel-igb-driver-and-quad-port-i211-gigabit-card/4001 ("... The only way to fix it, without rebooting, is to reload the igb kernel module and restart all IPFire networks!").

Comment: I did tried the "modprobe -r" as I stated above. Both links you posted reported a simliar problem but they didn't give any glue on how to solve it.

Comment: @josircg - A few notes:
1) `modprobe -r ...` followed by `sleep ... ` might have worked (but it didn't).
2) The second link I posted **does provide** several *clues* to possible solutions.
3) I suggest you take a few actions, which will certainly help others help you. Some are shown in the answer. Plus, it is good if you post the output or result of each specific solution suggested (or, if you did not try it, at least mention why so others know).
Cheers!

Comment: Sorry if I seem harsh Sancho. It was not my intention. It's just the rush. I did tried the sleep also but it didn't work either.

Comment: About rebooting: I can reboot. This is not the problem. I'm looking for a permanent solution because everytime I reboot, the error ocurrs again.

Comment: About the "PCIe link lost". This message is saved on system log just after the network hang.

Comment: About "pcie_aspm=off" - this options is used on kernel boot parameter. This is detailed on my original question: https://serverfault.com/questions/193114/linux-e1000e-intel-networking-driver-problems-galore-where-do-i-start

Comment: @josircg - Not a problem. Still, please try being specific, and accounting for each of the suggestions.
I might have missed it, but I don't see anything about:
1. Up/downgrading the kernel version.
2. Context lines.
3. Posting the exact commands you used to get `... PCIe link lost`, e.g. I infer it is `dmesg`, but trust me, at zero cost, posting them generally helps others help you.
Just think that the more readable the question, the better help you get.
Please see edited answer.

Comment: Just to help others with the same problem: when I downgrade the kernel, the problem remains. Yesterday, I received a new kernel upgrade notice, I upgraded it and the problem stops since then.

Comment: igb driver is working fine with Kernel 5.4.0-71-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: @josircg - Excellent! It is good that you found a solution, and that you post feedback (often missing).